# how to get radibutton Postion from listview On Button click in android

Tags: android

This is my screenshot:

[image]

This is my adapter class:

```
public class ListofAddressesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListofAddressesDataModel> {

    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap;
    private List<ListofAddressesDataModel> data;
    int selectedPosition = 0;
    String name, phone, address;
    String customeraddressid;

    public ListofAddressesAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                                  List<ListofAddressesDataModel> data) {
        super(context, R.layout.listofaddresses, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvsubservices);
            holder.description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvdesc);
            holder.fulladd = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvfulladdr);
            holder.r = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
            holder.delet = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivdelete);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }


        final ListofAddressesDataModel item = data.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(item.getName());
        holder.description.setText(item.getPhone());
        holder.fulladd.setText(item.getFulladdress());
        holder.r.setChecked(position == selectedPosition);
        holder.r.setTag(position);

        holder.r.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectedPosition = (Integer) view.getTag();
                name = data.get(selectedPosition).getName();
                phone = data.get(selectedPosition).getPhone();
                address = data.get(selectedPosition).getFulladdress();
                customeraddressid = data.get(selectedPosition).getCustaddid();


                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });



        return row;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView description;
        TextView fulladd;
        RadioButton r;
        ImageView delet;

    }

    public Object getItemAtPosition(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



}
```

This is my activity class:

```
public class testclass extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    List<ListofAddressesDataModel> lstDataModel;
    ListView add;
    JSONArray _jsonarray;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        add = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.add);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        add=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.add);
        lstDataModel=new ArrayList<>();
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        new manageaddresses().execute();


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button)
        {

        }
    }

    class manageaddresses extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String response = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://cpanel.smartindiaservice.com/api/CustomerAddresses?CustomerID=4");
            try {
                _jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < _jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    ListofAddressesDataModel datamodel = new ListofAddressesDataModel();
                    jsonObject = _jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);


                    String customeraddressid = jsonObject.getString("CustomerAddressID");
                    datamodel.setCustaddid(customeraddressid);
                    String fullname = jsonObject.getString("FullName");
                    datamodel.setName(fullname);
                    String housenumber = jsonObject.getString("HouseNumber");
                    String phonenumber = jsonObject.getString("PhoneNumber");
                    datamodel.setPhone(phonenumber);
                    String area = jsonObject.getString("Area");
                    String landmark = jsonObject.getString("Landmark");

                    String city = jsonObject.getString("City");

                    String fulladdress = housenumber + "," + " " + area + "," + " " + landmark + "," + " " + city;
                    datamodel.setFulladdress(fulladdress);
                    lstDataModel.add(datamodel);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            ListofAddressesAdapter adapter = new ListofAddressesAdapter(testclass.this, R.layout.listofaddresses, lstDataModel);

            add.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my item.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:buttonTint="#999999"
            android:text="New RadioButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvsubservices"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvdesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvsubservices"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvfulladdr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvdesc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custaddidposition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="position"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to get selected radio button position or value and id so that on button click I tried with but it always take first position. Can any one suggest me where am I doing wrong? I have to get selected radio button position so that I can get value from list of Objects. I have to send into next activity.

Comment: in `getView()` you have position, use it

Comment: how to apply on button click i have tried

Comment: On click of button in activity, you need which position is selected in list?

Comment: remove static from ViewHolder class

Comment: yes @AkshayBhat  i need what ever radio button we select that value i need in actvity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In adapter create a method which returns the object of selected position. Like :

```
public ListofAddressesDataModel getSelectedItem() {
    return data.get(selectedPosition);
}
```

In activity, on click of the button call this method. Like :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button) {
        //Here you will get the selected item of which the radio button is checked
        ListofAddressesDataModel selectedItem = ((ListofAddressesAdapter) add.getAdapter()).getSelectedItem();
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**
Instead of below lines in `getView()` in adapter

```
holder.r.setTag(position);
holder.r.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            selectedPosition = (Integer) view.getTag();
            name = data.get(selectedPosition).getName();
            phone = data.get(selectedPosition).getPhone();
            address = data.get(selectedPosition).getFulladdress();
            customeraddressid = data.get(selectedPosition).getCustaddid();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

just replace it with below line

```
holder.r.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            selectedPosition = position;
        }
});
```